# Why is bzip2 needed in the kernel patch instructions?

Tags: kernel, patch

This is from [here](http://wiki.karen.net.nz/index.php/Network_Diagnostic_Tool_%28NDT%29).

**Extract the patch**

```
tar -xvzf /usr/src/web100-2.5.22-200810130047.tar.gz

bzip2 web100/ web100-2.6.27-2.5.22-200810130047.patch
```

**Test the patch**

```
bzip2 -dc /usr/src/linux/web100/ web100-2.6.27-2.5.22-200810130047.patch.bz2 | patch -p1 --dry-run
```

I looked at the `.patch`, the diff output of many files and the file `.patch.bz2` after the bzip2 command which is too also the diff output of many files, they seem to be the same. My question is why is `bzip2` even needed to turn the `.patch` into a `.patch.bz2`? Is it for the redirection to std output from the `-dc` option for the patch command? Even if it is, why not just not just use the patch command in the form something like this:`patch -p1 < patchfile`? I don't see why the `bzip2` is done here. Thanks!

Also, I think the `bzip2` might have an extra space in the command after `web100/`, right?

Comment: Yeah, those instructions seem pretty messed up. It could definitely use some loving.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's unneeded. Those instructions could be abbreviated to:

```
tar -xvzf /usr/src/web100-2.5.22-200810130047.tar.gz
patch -p1 --dry-run < web100/ web100-2.6.27-2.5.22-200810130047.patch
```

Comment: hmm, ok. i was stumped for a while. A few different sites actually all had this version. Thanks for the abbreviated version!

Comment: Note that you'll need to remove '--dry-run' to actually apply the patch